# Texas Hold'em on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, backwards-compatibility, texas-hold-em

Why is it that, when I'm playing this game on Xbox One and my family is playing on  the Xbox 360, I can't join their game and they can't send me invites to join them? I thought it was backward compatible.

Comment: Only certain games are backwards compatible. Also a Xbox 360 can't connect to a one.

Comment: Backwards compatible games are not always guaranteed to share servers with their 360 counterparts, but it does happen. A 360 user and an XB1 user can party up in borderlands. It's most likely a choice by the developers.